# Design pattern for filtering/counting a collection in various states/steps

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, linq-to-sql

I'm starting with an IEnumerable and want to run it through several methods that contain LINQ-to-SQL queries, which will filter the result set. Some methods will operate on the original result set, others will operate on a further-filtered result set. However, I want to retain a count of the Excepts (anti-intersections?) of the supplied IEnumerable A and the filtered IEnumerable B so the counts can be sent in an email at the end of all filtering methods. For instance, if Method A is provided a collection of 60 records, but after filtering, the result is down to 20 records, I want to store the number 40 somewhere.

What is the recommended way of keeping track of the counts and collections/queries? I was thinking of using IQueryable and doing Count() within the methods with an out parameter to track the counts, but that just seems messy. Is there some sort of design pattern that fits this process?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are asking. Can you not just subtract 60 and 20 later on and get 40?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IFilter<T>
{
     IQueryable<T> Filter(IQueryAble<T> data);
}

interface IResultSet<T>
{
    int OrignalCount { get; }
    int FilteredCount { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Result { get; }
    void AddFilter(IFilter<T> filter);
}
```

and the implementation of IResultSet:

```
class ResultSet<T> : IResultSet<T>
{
     private IQueryable<T> data;
     private List<IFilter> filters = new List<IFilter>();
     public int OriginalCount {get; private set;}
     public int FilteredCount 
     {
         get { return Result.Count(); }
     }

     public IEnumerable<T> Result 
     {
         get 
         {
             IQueryable data = this.data;
             foreach(IFilter filter in filters)
             {
                 data = filter.Filter(data);
             }
             return data;
         }
     }

     //constructor
     public ResultSet<T>(IQueryable<T> data)
     {
          this.data = data;
          this.OriginalCount = data.Count();              
     }

     public void AddFilter(IFilter<T> filter)
     {
         this.filters.Add(filter);
     }
}
```